# Continuous function from the closed unit disk to itself being identity on the boundary must be surjective?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

If there is a continuous function from the closed unit disk to itself such that it is identity map on boundary, must it be onto?

Comment: Homeomorphisms are always surjective. You mean just a continuous map?

Comment: Sorry I have revised it.

Comment: "hjhjhj57" thank you!

Comment: David, you can tag users using "@"! This way they'll get a notification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

Suppose $f: D^2 \to D^2$ did not have $p \in D^2$ in the image, and such that $f$ restricts to the identity on the boundary. One may pick a homeomorphism $g: D^2 \to D^2$ that restricts to the identity on the boundary, with $g(p) = 0$, so $gf: D^2 \to D^2$ misses $0$.

Now compose with the map $D^2 \to S^1, x \mapsto x/\|x\|$. This defines a retraction $D^2 \to S^1$. But that's silly, as if there were such a retraction, the map $\pi_1(S^1) \to \pi_1(D^2)$ induced by the inclusion would be an injection, and it's not.

Comment: Thank you. 
Also, "I'm wondering if there exists a fixed point in the D's interior"

Comment: @David I think there should be, but I don't have a proof in mind yet. You should post this as a separate question.

Comment: I've revised it.

Comment: @David: The new question is fundamentally a different question than the first one. Generally, if you have multiple (but only a little related) questions, you should post them each separately. I'm suggesting you post this one as a new question.

Comment: Ok!thanks for your suggestion and I'm wondering how to construct
the function g in your proof.

Comment: Pick a self-homeomorphism $g'$ of the unit disc that takes $p$ to $0$. (You can do this very explicitly; [here are the ones you want](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141735/automorphisms-of-the-unit-disc).) On the boundary, say $g'$ restricts to $h$; extend $h^{-1}$ to an automorphism of the unit disc using the [Alexander trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander%27s_trick). Call this, uh, $h'$? Then $h'g'$ is the desired homeomorphism.

Comment: Got it thank you very much!

Comment: If you want to do this in any dimension, it's a bit harder, because you can't resort to picking an easy self-homeomorphism like up there. But it's still true; one can prove it with some smooth manifold theory.